# Как изменить значение Resources.Strings?

Tags: c#

```
Resources.Strings.Name= "";
```

> Ошибка    CS0200  Невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору
>   "Strings.Name" — доступ только для чтения.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Ищет локализованную строку, похожую на Name.
    /// </summary>
    internal static string Name{
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("Name", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

Comment: По идее, все строковые константы хранятся в файле в открытом виде, их можно попарсить и изменить, других путей не знаю.

Comment: А вам точно именно ресурсы нужны, может достаточно файла настроек?

Comment: Сделан переключатель `Button_.Content = Strings.Name2;` Работает нормально.

Comment: ресурсы не поддерживают изменение в рантайме, и не должны. Для пользовательских настроек и временных данных можно использовать массу других вариантов.

Comment: @rdorn ответом, ответом, ну что вы всё в комментарии пишете.

Comment: @AK да как-то странно писать ответ, на то, что по запросу "resources C#" гугл выдает первой строчкой =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Документация: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx#Anchor_2

> При построении приложения Visual Studio вызывает средство resgen.exe для преобразования ресурсов приложения во внутренний класс с именем Resources. Этот класс находится в файле Resources.Designer.cs, который вложен в файл Resources.resx в Обозревателе решений. **Класс Resources инкапсулирует все ресурсы проекта в статические свойства get только для чтения**, что дает возможность получения строго-типизированных ресурсов во время выполнения.

Для пользовательских настроек и временных данных можно использовать массу других вариантов, от банального [Application.Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a65txexh.aspx), до полноценных баз данных.